# How to view OpenVPN connections?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to view the open connections between my OpenVPN client and server via the server. Not sure how to do this as tcpdump does not show anything, yet OpenVPN is working and running.

Again, when SSHing into my OpenVPN servers, all I can see are my SSH packets being sent over and nothing for OpenVPN. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: I really don't know sorry, but have you specified the correct interface? OpenVPN creates a new network interface, maybe you need to specify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVPN stores open connections in its status logs.  You can find the status logs by:

`grep '^status' /etc/openvpn/server*.conf`

in my case (Ubuntu) produces the following (I have two running OpenVPN instances):

```
/etc/openvpn/server6.conf:status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status6.log
/etc/openvpn/server.conf:status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
```

`cat /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log`

shows the following:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Sun Jul 24 22:42:55 2022
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
wino-surface6,10.9.4.1:20994,76104,10838,Sun Jul 24 22:42:22 2022
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
10.12.0.4,wino-surface6,10.9.4.1:20994,Sun Jul 24 22:42:54 2022
2001:db8::1002,wino-surface6,10.9.4.1:20994,Sun Jul 24 22:42:54 2022
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,0
END
```

You can see that there is a single client (wino-surface6) that has 2 ip addresses assigned (an IPv4 and an IPv6) by the first OpenVPN instance.

As to why tcpdump isn't seeing the OpenVPN packets, you need to make sure you're looking for the correct protocol and port. You can verify this with:

`egrep '^(port|proto)' /etc/openvpn/server*.conf`